# How can I adjust this route so that I can pass in additional paramaters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I don't understand the necessity for nested routes. There are many things about Rails routes that I DO understand.

Here is my simple setup in this Rails 3.2 application:

```
Categories habtm Products
```

In routes.rb:

```
resources :categories do
  member do
    get 'list_products_in'
    post 'add_to'
    post 'remove_from'
  end
end

resources :products
```

I have basically created a page from which to add products to a category. There is a select box at the top containing the products, and at the bottom is the list. To add a product to the list, you choose one from the select box and click the "Add" button. "add_to" is called via Ajax. Works great.

My problem is that to make this app degrade gracefully, I want it to work without Ajax also. But none of my routes work properly.

I know from the above that my custom routes are not expecting a product_id to be passed in addition to the category id. My question is, how can I add more parameters to my custom routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:variable` segments in your routes to supply additional variable segments.

For example, you could add a `product_id` segment to your `add_to` and `remove_from` routes:

```
...
post 'add_to/:product_id'
post 'remove_from/:product_id'
```

Comment: I tried that, but "rake routes" then gives me: "missing :action"

Comment: I think this did it for me:


      match 'add_to/:product_id' => 'categories#add_to', :as => 'add_to', :via => :post